# Bolding for forum posts in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a script that'll activate the bold forum code ([b]) when pressing CTRL+B on the first time, and that'll deactivate it ([/b]) on the second press.
However I can't understand the instructions at all.
Would it be too much trouble to ask for somebody to do this for me, or at least tell me where I can find instructions that can teach newcomers like me?

Comment: Welcome!  We're not a script writing service, and just posting links to instructions is off-topic. Please edit your question to include what you have tried already, and point out where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Apologies. I would like to mention that I learned more from Wutnaut in his one simple post than I did in all the instructions I read for AutoHotKey, and would like to thank him for that. I will delete this post in a few hours just so people can process my apologies before I do so. Again, sorry for the inconvenience, will not bother again.

Comment: Well you could upvote his answer and give him a few rep points if you want to thank him. :)  No point in apologizing or deleting the question. Even if it gets closed, having it may still be useful to future visitors.  For the future, perhaps take a bit of time to peruse the help section to learn what's expected here and how to use the site. :)

Comment: I tried to upvote but I'm a guest user and don't have the minimum 15 rep. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
^b::
Send, [b]
return

!b::
Send, [/b]
return
```

The first one is Ctrl+b, 2nd is Alt+b. As far as I know, you can't make the same button input do 2 different things, or rather, the code would get very complicated.

Comment: You can do it by simply adding a counter and reset it if it has been reached a number. But as techie007 says, this is not a scripting writing service.

Comment: If the script were any longer, I'd agree with you. In this particular case, I don't mind throwing them a bone. Thanks for the tip on adding a counter, I'm sure I'll make use of it.